# Netlify function CORS issue

Tags: cors, netlify

I have a CORS issue on my netlify functions.
[image]

Here's my `netlify.toml` but it doesn't help at all.
Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1):

**You have missed an indent after the `for = "/*"` line**

```
  [[headers]]
      # Define which paths this specific [[headers]] block will cover.
      for = "/*"
        [headers.values]
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

Inspect the build log, and you can easily find the rejection of the false rule by **Netlify**.

More ref - https://answers.netlify.com/t/access-control-allow-origin-policy/1813/2